# Entity framework Data Access Layer project's connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, data-access-layer

I have this project made by someone else that's I'm refering in mine; it's a data access layer using Entity Framework.

So of course, when I compile my project, I have my executable, with its .config file.

Here's the kicker: How can I tell the data access layer DLL to which server and with which credentials to connect to it ?

If I open the DAL DLL in Notepad, I do see the connection strings hardcoded in it.

I have modified the DAL project to be able to handle many connection strings, but once compiled, it's baked in it.

Am I misunderstanding the internal workings of EF ?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely want to store the credentials into some type of configuration file. There are several ways this can be done. Take a look at the following MSDN article: [Security Considerations (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760.aspx)